# openshift postgres: No suitable driver on tomcat

Tags: java, postgresql, tomcat

I have moved my apps from localhost to OpenShift, and found problem with PostgreSQL connection.
I have configured *pom.xml*:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>9.4-1204-jdbc41</version>
</dependency>
```

and *persistence.xml*:

```
    <persistence-unit name="expenseSystem">
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://$OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_HOST:$OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_PORT/new" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="$OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_USERNAME" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="$OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_PASSWORD" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="300" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="3000" />
<!--            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/> -->
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
```

but in log I've still found:

```
Oct 29, 2015 6:11:08 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.10.Final}
Oct 29, 2015 6:11:08 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Oct 29, 2015 6:11:08 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Oct 29, 2015 6:11:08 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
Oct 29, 2015 6:11:08 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator instantiateExplicitConnectionProvider
INFO: HHH000130: Instantiating explicit connection provider: org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider
Oct 29, 2015 6:11:08 AM org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider configure
INFO: HHH010002: C3P0 using driver: org.postgresql.Driver at URL: jdbc:postgresql://$OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_HOST:$OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_PORT/new
Oct 29, 2015 6:11:08 AM org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider configure
INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=$OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_USERNAME, password=****}
Oct 29, 2015 6:11:08 AM org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider configure
INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
Oct 29, 2015 6:11:08 AM com.mchange.v2.log.MLog <clinit>
INFO: MLog clients using java 1.4+ standard logging.
Oct 29, 2015 6:11:08 AM com.mchange.v2.c3p0.C3P0Registry banner
INFO: Initializing c3p0-0.9.2.1 [built 20-March-2013 10:47:27 +0000; debug? true; trace: 10]
Oct 29, 2015 6:11:09 AM com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource getPoolManager
INFO: Initializing c3p0 pool... com.mchange.v2.c3p0.PoolBackedDataSource@c4a86e25 [ connectionPoolDataSource -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource@e71f40d [ acquireIncrement -> 3, acquireRetryAttempts -> 30, acquireRetryDelay -> 1000, autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 0, connectionCustomizerClassName -> null, connectionTesterClassName -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester, debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces -> false, factoryClassLocation -> null, forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false, identityToken -> 1bqonyz9c1dory2qrezkfd|5edf64, idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 3000, initialPoolSize -> 3, maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0, maxConnectionAge -> 0, maxIdleTime -> 300, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 0, maxPoolSize -> 15, maxStatements -> 0, maxStatementsPerConnection -> 0, minPoolSize -> 3, nestedDataSource -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource@f0b8d1c4 [ description -> null, driverClass -> null, factoryClassLocation -> null, identityToken -> 1bqonyz9c1dory2qrezkfd|1019b35, jdbcUrl -> jdbc:postgresql://$OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_HOST:$OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_PORT/new, properties -> {user=******, password=******} ], preferredTestQuery -> null, propertyCycle -> 0, statementCacheNumDeferredCloseThreads -> 0, testConnectionOnCheckin -> false, testConnectionOnCheckout -> true, unreturnedConnectionTimeout -> 0, usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies -> false; userOverrides: {} ], dataSourceName -> null, factoryClassLocation -> null, identityToken -> 1bqonyz9c1dory2qrezkfd|b0612a, numHelperThreads -> 3 ]
Oct 29, 2015 6:11:39 AM com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask run
WARNING: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@2ef080 -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt exception:
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
```

When I change *persistence.xml* to connect to my localhost database, everything is OK.
So I thing this is credentials problem, but I can not find it.

Answer (score 0):

I also discovered some specific problems when moved my application to OpenShift hosting. One important moment which I understoond that OpenShift prefer works with datasources instead of establishing direct connection.
Did you tried next approach from [OpenShift blog](https://blog.openshift.com/jndi-tomcat-configuration-howto/)?
Quick guide is next:

1. Define proper datasource in Tomcat `server.xml`:

   ```
   <Resource name="jdbc/postgresqldb" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
     username="${env.OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_USERNAME}"
     password="${env.OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_PASSWORD}"
     url="jdbc:postgresql://${env.OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_HOST}:${env.OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_PORT}/${env.OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME}"
     driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver" initialSize="5" maxWait="5000"
     maxActive="120" maxIdle="5" validationQuery="select 1"
     poolPreparedStatements="true">
   </Resource>
   ```
2. The next change you have to make is in `context.xml`. You have to define a resource link to the datasource as shown below

   ```
   <ResourceLink name="jdbc/postgresqldb" global="jdbc/postgresqldb" type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
   ```
3. Download correct version of PostgreSQL JDBC Driver (currently OpenShift used version 9.2)

   ```
   cd $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR
   wget http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/postgresql/postgresql/9.2-1003-jdbc4/postgresql-9.2-1003-jdbc4.jar
   ```
4. Next update the `catalina.properties` in your application `.openshift/config` folder to scan the OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR as shown below. We are using `catalina.home` system property to get the OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR path.

   ```
   common.loader=${catalina.base}/lib,${catalina.base}/lib/*.jar,${catalina.home}/lib,${catalina.home}/lib/*.jar,${catalina.home}/../data/*.jar
   ```
5. Now you can push the changes to OpenShift as shown below.

   ```
   git commit -am "made changes for tomcat jndi datasource"
   git push
   ```
6. Change your persistence.xml as follow

   ```
   <persistence>
      <persistence-unit name="REQUIRED_PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME_GOES_HERE">
         <non-jta-data-source>jdbc/myDS</non-jta-data-source>
         <!--OTHER YOUR HIBERNATE PROPERTIES-->
      </persistence-unit>
   </persistence>
   ```

I hope this manual will help you.
Almost same steps described also in another blog post [here](http://fanaticjava.blogspot.com/2012/11/connecting-tomcat-with-postgesql-on.html).